# Convergence of fraction of expectation values

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, stochastic-processes, asymptotics, stochastic-calculus

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be iid normal random variables.

I am looking for a strategy to establish the following limit for fraction of expectation values

$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{E(\prod_{1\le i < j\le n} \vert X_i-X_j \vert^{1/n})}{E(\prod_{1\le i < j\le n-1} \vert X_i-X_j \vert^{1/n})}=1.$$

Does anybody have any ideas what to use for this limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Mehta integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selberg_integral#Mehta's_integral) is 
$$M_n(\gamma):=E\prod_{1\le i<j\le n}|X_i-X_j|^{2\gamma}
=\prod_{j=1}^n\frac{\Gamma(1+j\gamma)}{\Gamma(1+\gamma)}.$$
So, your fraction under the limit sign is 
$$\frac{M_n(1/(2n))}{M_{n-1}(1/(2n)}=\frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{\Gamma(1+1/(2n))}\to\Gamma(3/2)\approx0.886227.$$

Comment: thank you, what a nice way of seeing this. I am just wondering: Imagine we would not have this explicit formula at hand, do you see any way to give upper/lower bounds on the limiting value?

Comment: @Sascha : Another way to find the limit is to use (say) Theorem 3.1 of Chen and Shao https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bj/1179498762 for U-statistics, since $\sum_{1\le i<j \le n}\ln|X_i-X_j|$ is a U-statistic. This will work even without the normality assumption on the $X_i$'s. If you want more details, post this additional question separately.

Answer (score 1):

The numerator and denominator can also be written as 
$$E\left[\exp\left(\frac1n\sum\ln|X_i-X_j|\right)\right]$$
where the numerator has $n(n-1)/2$ summands and the denominator has $(n-1)(n-2)/2$ summands.

Let $\mu$ and $\sigma$ be the mean and standard deviation of $\ln|X_i-X_j|$. Since $X_i-X_j$ is a normal distribution with mean $0$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{2}$,
$$\mu=E\left[\ln\Big|N(0,\sqrt{2})\Big|\right]=\frac{-\gamma}{2}$$
where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant#Integrals).

*If the summands were independent*, then the fraction in the question would be approximated by a ratio of means of lognormal distributions:

$$
\frac
{E\left[LN\left(\frac{n(n-1)}{2n}\mu,\sqrt{\frac{n(n-1)}{2n^2}}\sigma\right)\right]}
{E\left[LN\left(\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2n}\mu,\sqrt{\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2n^2}}\sigma\right)\right]}
=
\frac
{\exp\left(\frac{n(n-1)}{2n}\mu+\frac{n(n-1)}{2n^2}\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)}
{\exp\left(\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2n}\mu+\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2n^2}\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)}
$$

In the limit this is
$$
\exp\left(\frac{2(n-1)}{2n}\mu+\frac{2(n-1)}{2n^2}\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)
\rightarrow
\exp(\mu)=\exp(-\gamma/2) \sim 0.749.$$

Empirically the number seems to be between that and $1$.

With some numerical integration we could compute $\sigma$ and the correlation $\rho$ between $\ln|X_i-X_j|$ and $\ln|X_i-X_k|$; with some combinatorics we could compute how often those $\rho$'s show up in the standard deviations of the two lognormals; combining those results we could get a more accurate value for the overall expectation.